# Как получить значение у select в customizer (wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, cms

Всем привет, вообщем я создал в кастомайзере секцию и в нее добавил `select`, выглядит это таким образом.

```
$wp_customize->add_section( "theme_page" , array(
      'title' => "Выбор страницы",
                'priority' => 21)
);
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'theme_page_value', array(
       'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
       'sanitize_callback' => 'themeslug_sanitize_select',
       'default' => 'value1',
));
$wp_customize->add_control( 'theme_page_value', array(
        'type' => 'select',
        'section' => 'theme_page',
        'label' => ( 'Выберите страницу' ),
        'choices' => array(
          'value1' => ( 'Главная' ),
          'value2' => ( 'О нас' ),
          'value3' => ( 'Наши услуги' ),
          'value4' => ( 'Портфолио' ),
          'value5' => ( 'Корзина' ),
          'value6' => ( 'Другие услуги' ),
          'value7' => ( 'Базовые услуги' ),
        ),
));
```

А таким образом я пытаюсь получить значение:

```
<?php echo get_theme_mod('theme_page_value'); ?>
```

Но почему-то я всегда получаю **value1**, так же почему-то кастомайзер выводит предупреждение: ***Неверное значение***.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я делаю не так?

P.s. Я искал похожие ситуации в интернете, но отыскать решения не получилось...

Comment: Похоже, причина та же: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/889122/220220

Comment: Да, похоже на то. Спасибо)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось что я пропустил функцию. В конечном итоге мой код пришел к такому виду:

```
$wp_customize->add_section( "theme_page" , array(
    'title' => "Выбор страницы",
    'priority' => 21)
);

$wp_customize->add_setting( 'theme_page_value', array(
    'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
    'sanitize_callback' => 'theme_page_select',
    'default' => 'value1',
));

$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Control( 
  $wp_customize, 
  'theme_page_value',
  array(
    'label'    => __( 'Dark or light theme version?', 'theme_name' ),
    'section'  => 'theme_page',
    'settings' => 'theme_page_value',
    'type'     => 'select',
    'choices'  => array(
      'value1' => __( 'Главная' ),
      'value2' => __( 'О нас' ),
      'value3' => __( 'Наши услуги' ),
      'value4' => __( 'Портфолио' ),
      'value5' => __( 'Корзина' ),
      'value6' => __( 'Другие услуги' ),
      'value7' => __( 'Базовые услуги' )
    ),
  )
));

function theme_page_select( $input, $setting ) {
  $input = sanitize_key( $input );
  $choices = $setting->manager->get_control( $setting->id )->choices;
  return ( array_key_exists( $input, $choices ) ? $input : $setting->default );
}
```

Может, кому пригодится.